# Creating a dictionary another sorted dictionary (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary were each entry is formated like this: ("word":4, "word2":6 ...).  I want to create a new dictionary which consists of only the 10 entries in the old dictionary with the highest values.  Anyone know how i would do that?

Comment: i just dont really know where to start. I guess it has something to do with sort but?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `collection.Counter` from the dictionary, get the [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) words and create a new `dict` from the returned list of tuples:

```
>>> d = {"word%d"%i : random.randint(0,100) for i in range(10)}
>>> dict(collections.Counter(d).most_common(5))
{'word4': 92, 'word2': 83, 'word3': 89, 'word5': 72, 'word9': 47}
```

Or more "manually", using `sorted` with a special `key` function and slicing, same result:

```
>>> dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: -t[1])[:5])
```